# How to do a small calculation on a drop down when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a form that requires a calculation when clicked on a multiple drop down selector, and still displays the clicks of the courses in real time and lastly calculates the sum total of the courses.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div { color:blue; }
    div#five { color:red; }

    div#show_box {
    background: wheat;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    }

    div#total_box {
    width: 119px;
    height: 60px;
    background: pink;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="one"></div>
 <div id="two"></div>
 <div id="three"></div>
 <div id="four"></div>
 <div id="five"></div>

<script>
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];
var obj = { one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4, five:5 };

jQuery.each(arr, function() {
  $("#" + this).text("Mine is " + this + ".");
   return (this != "three"); // will stop running after "three"
});

jQuery.each(obj, function(i, val) {
  $("#" + i).append(document.createTextNode(" - " + val));
});
</script>



<select id="wow" multiple="multiple">
<option id="def" value="default selected">select a course</option>
<option id="mth" value="1">math</option>
<option id="eng" value="2">english</option>
<option id="chm" value="3">chem</option>
<option id="phy" value="4">physics</option>
</select>



<div id="show_box">
<h6 id="1"></h6>
<h6 id="2"></h6>
<h6 id="3"></h6>
<h6 id="4"></h6>
<h6 id="5"></h6>

</div>

<div id="total_box">

</div>


<script>

//list all the view more in the clicks into arrays...
            var vm_id=[1,2,3,4,5];



            jQuery.each(vm_id, function() {
                //$('button[value="' + this + "]')
              $('option[value="' + this + '"]').one('click',function()
                {
                    //this.value
                    var price=["2000","3000","4000","5000","6000"];
                    if (this.value == 1) 
                    {
                        $('#show_box > #1').html(price[0]);
                        $('#1').after("<input type='hidden' id='2000' value=" + price[0] + ">");
                        /*
                        $('option[value="' + this + '"]').off('click','option[value="' + this + '"]',function()
                        {
                            $('#2000').remove('#2000');
                        });
                        */

                    };

                    if (this.value == 2) 
                    {
                        $('#show_box > #2').html(price[1]);
                        $('#2').after("<input type='hidden' id='3000' value=" + price[1] + ">");
                    };

                    if (this.value == 3) 
                    {
                        $('#show_box > #3').html(price[2]);
                        $('#3').after("<input type='hidden' id='4000' value=" + price[2] + ">");
                    };

                    if (this.value == 4) 
                    {
                        $('#show_box > #4').html(price[3]);
                        $('#4').after("<input type='hidden' id='5000' value=" + price[3] + ">");
                    };

                    if (this.value == 5) 
                    {
                      $('#show_box > #5').html(price[4]);
                      $('#5').after("<input type='hidden' id='6000' value=" + price[4] + ">");
                    };


                    //$("input:hidden").length
                    //alert($("input:hidden").length);
                    $("input:hidden").each(function(index,Element)
                      {
                          var sub=$("input:hidden").index();
                          var in_len=$("input:hidden").length;


                          if ((in_len == 1))  
                            {
                                //var get_id=Element.id;
                                var ids=[1000,2000,3000,4000,5000];

                                $.each(ids,function(index,value)
                                  {
                                    var get_id=Element.id;

                                      if (get_id == this) 
                                      {
                                          $('#total_box').text(value);
                                          //console.log(get_id + ':' + index + '=' + value);
                                      };
                                  });

                            };

                          if ((in_len == 2))  
                            {

                              var ids=[1000,2000,3000,4000,5000];

                                $.each(ids,function(index,value)
                                  {
                                    var get_id=Element.id;

                                      if (get_id == this) 
                                      {
                                          var in_len=$("input:hidden");
                                          one=in_len[0].id;
                                          two=in_len[1].id;

                                          one=parseInt(one);
                                          two=parseInt(two);
                                          three= one + two;
                                          $('#total_box').text(three);

                                          //console.log(get_id + ':' + index + '=' + value);

                                      };
                                  });
                              //var get_id=Element.id;
                                /*
                                var ids=[1000,2000,3000,4000,5000];

                                $.each(ids,function(index,value)
                                  {
                                    var get_id=Element.id;

                                      //console.log(get_id + ':' + index + '=' + value);
                                  });
                                */

                            };

                          if ((in_len == 3))  
                            {
                              var ids=[1000,2000,3000,4000,5000];

                                $.each(ids,function(index,value)
                                  {
                                    var get_id=Element.id;

                                      if (get_id == this) 
                                      {
                                          var in_len=$("input:hidden");
                                          one=in_len[0].id;
                                          two=in_len[1].id;
                                          three=in_len[2].id;

                                          one=parseInt(one);
                                          two=parseInt(two);
                                          three=parseInt(three);
                                          four= one + two + three;
                                          $('#total_box').text(four);
                                          //console.log(get_id + ':' + index + '=' + value);
                                      };
                                  });

                            };

                          if ((in_len == 4))  
                            {
                                var ids=[1000,2000,3000,4000,5000];

                                $.each(ids,function(index,value)
                                  {
                                    var get_id=Element.id;

                                      if (get_id == this) 
                                      {
                                          price=[2000,3000,4000,5000,6000];
                                          p1=price[0];
                                          p2=price[1];
                                          p3=price[2];
                                          p4=price[3];

                                          $('#total_box').text(p1+p2+p3+p4);
                                      };
                                  });
                            };
                      });

                });
            });

 /*
$('#mth').click(function()
{
    var wow_val=document.getElementById('mth').value;
    alert(wow_val);
});
*/

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have solved the problem with this code, but I want to see other ways to solve it from other developers.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the purpose of the script inside the first <script>-tag and the div-elements before it? Are they relevant to the question?

Comment: assuming you have run it you will see that there is a drop down box box with two divs the display div and the total divs. so what really happens is that when the user click on any of the dropdown it shows the price of the course and the total box summates the whole process.. please just show me if there is another way to go about it.

Comment: Yes, but above the dropdown there are elements too, that seem to have no relevance in your actual question. I'd suggest only posting the relevant parts here, it makes the answers more relevant too.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, the functionality you want is:

- Displaying the prices of all the selected items separately
- Displaying the sum of prices of items that are selected

I'd do this by adding the price information directly to the html option elements, for example as [HTML5 data-attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/):

```
<select id="wow" multiple="multiple">
    <option id="def" value="default" selected>select a course</option>
    <option id="mth" data-price="2000" value="1">math</option>
    <option id="eng" data-price="3000" value="2">english</option>
    <option id="chm" data-price="4000" value="3">chem</option>
    <option id="phy" data-price="5000" value="4">physics</option>
</select>
<div id="show_box"></div>
<div id="total_box"></div>
```

Then bind the handling function to the "change"-event of the select-element:

```
$('#wow').change(function() {
    // Remove any previously set values
    $('#show_box, #total_box').empty();
    var sum = 0,
        price;
    $(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
        // Check that the attribute exist, so that any unset values won't bother
        if ($(this).attr('data-price')) {            
            price = $(this).data('price');
            sum += price;
            $('#show_box').append('<h6>' + price + '</h6>');
        }
    });
    $('#total_box').text(sum);
});
```

And that's it. See [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xKL44/2/) to see it in action.

A couple of points about your question:

- Your code is overall rather messy. It really pays off later if you name your variables clearly, add comments to some obscure parts of the code, and remove obsolete old commented-out bits. You should also separate your JS and CSS to separate files for maintainability.
- Having to bind information (price) about the content (courses) directly in javascript should be avoided. Your JS should handle the logic, and your HTML should provide the content. If you decided to add another selectable option, that would require altering some 8-10 places in your code, but just 1 in mine, where logic and content is separate.
- In general if you find that you have multiple very similar if-statements in a row, there would almost certainly be a better, DRYer way.
- When posting your questions here, please only provide the relevant code and clean up the obsolete commented-out parts.

Comment: thanks Waiski for your review i will look into it... i check the jsfiddle link it is ok in your own way but it is not calculating the sum of clicks clicked and displaying it to the total box.

Comment: @user3223851 It calculates the sum of the prices of the selected elements, I thought that's what you wanted. So do you need to store the total number of times the element has been clicked? Or how many elements are selected in total? Please specify what is it exactly that you want, "calculating the sum of clicks clicked" is slightly ambiguous.

Comment: the main thing is to display and calculate it based on the clicks. @Waiski